# Why is the Point Spread Function of a diffraction limited lens the Fourier transform of the Aperture Function?

Tags: optics, imaging

I understand that only part of the spherical wave emerging from a point source in the object plane can be captured by the lens and so only a partial converging wave creates the image as shown on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PSF.svg) but I don't understand the Fourier transform justification next to it:

"It can be shown (see Fourier optics, Huygens–Fresnel principle, Fraunhofer diffraction) that the field radiated by a planar object (or, by reciprocity, the field converging onto a planar image) is related to its corresponding source (or image) plane distribution via a Fourier transform (FT) relation"

But the object is a delta function... are we talking about the planar object right within the lens?

Comment: What is a "PSF"?

Comment: Point Spread Function

Comment: Real space and momentum space are related by the Fourier transform. By limiting the transverse real space part of the wave function, you spread it in momentum space.

Comment: Isn't the PSF the Fourier transform of the modulation transfer function MTF? (or vice versa)? As PSF describes how a point is smeared in image space, while MTF describes how well spatial frequency of object space (meaning spatial detail) is preserved in image space?

Comment: this may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/643740/does-a-lens-always-act-as-a-fourier-transform/643750#643750